# SSH keys keep getting deleted from Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: docker, ssh, google-compute-engine

**Background:**

- I am running a Google Compute Engine VM, called `host`.
- There is a Docker container running on the machine called `container`.
- I connect to the VM using an account called `user@gmail.com`.
- I need to connect through `ssh` from the `container` to the `host`, without being prompted for the `user` password.

**Problem:**

Minutes after successfully connecting from the container to the host, the `user/.ssh/authorized_keys` gets "modified" by some process from Google itself. As far as I understood this process appends some ssh keys needed to connect to the VM. In my case though, the process seems to overwrite the key that I generated from the container.

**Setup:**

I connect to `host` using Google Compute Engine GUI, pressing on the SSH button.

[image: ssh]

Then I follow the steps described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/20921) on AskUbuntu.
I set the password for `user` on `host`:

```
user@host:~$ sudo passwd user
```

I set `PasswordAuthentication` to `yes` in `sshd_config`, and I restart `sshd`:

```
user@host:~$ sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
user@host:~$ sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

I enter in the Docker container using `bash`, I generate the key, and I copy it on the host:

```
user@host:~$ docker exec -it container /bin/bash
(base) root@container-id:# ssh-keygen
(base) root@container-id:# ssh-copy-id user@host
```

The key is successfully copied to the host, the host is added to the `known_hosts` file, and I am able to connect from the container to the host without being prompted for the password (as I gave it during the `ssh-copy-id` execution).

Now, if I detach from the host, let some time pass, and attach again, I find that the `user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file contains some keys generated by Google, but **there is no trace of my key** (the one that allows the container to connect to the host).

What puzzles me more than everything is that we consistently used this process before and we never had such problem. Some accounts on this same host have still keys from containers that no longer exist!

Does anyone has any idea about this behavior? Do you know about any solutions that let me keep the key for as long as it is needed?

Comment: Absolute royal pain in my ass because even though os-login is set to TRUE both VM and project wide, Google decides to change the permission and wipe the file every time! Infuriating! Go use AWS, they have a feature we need but beyond that its a much worse product.

Comment: Had the same problem.  very annoying.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone has trouble with this even **AFTER** adding SSH keys to the GCE metadata:

Make sure **your username is in the SSH key description section**!

For example, if your SSH key is

```
ssh-rsa AAAA...zzzz
```

and your login is `ubuntu`, make sure you actually enter

```
ssh-rsa AAAA...zzzz ubuntu
```

since it appears Google copies the key to the `authorized_keys` of the user specified inside the key.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the accounts daemon is doing this task. You could refer [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gce-discussion/iHqRb2KlMZg/x59xV4pYAQAJ) thread for more details about this.

You might find the [OS Login API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access) a easier management option. Once enabled, you can use a single [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/os-login/) or [API call](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/rest/v1beta/users/importSshPublicKey) to add SSH keys.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking for solution for this, I solved this issue by storing the SSH Keys in Compute Engine Metadata https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys